# How to select an element by an attribute of a tag in python

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to access the text of multiple tags using selenium in python.

The tags do not have attribute like `id` or `class`; they have an attribute named `itemprop`.

For instance there are multiple tags of such type:

```
<p itemprop="articleBody">
London's Gatwick Airport ........</p>
```

I can't use "select element by tag name" because there are tag "p" with different attributes which I don't want to include.

I am using the below code to select these elements:

```
elements = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, """p[itemprop='articleBody’]""")
```

However it throws the error - ......

> NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"p[itemprop='articleBody’]"}

How can I fix this?

Comment: Corrected Instance 
For instance there are multiple tags of such type
(p itemprop="articleBody")....London's Gatwick Airport ........(/p)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have smart quote `’` in the selector, use `find_elements*` with `s` to get multiple elements.

```
elements = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'p[itemprop="articleBody"]')
# Or
elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('p[itemprop="articleBody"]')
```

Comment: thank you. It worked. However, I did not understand the difference why single quotes did not work?

Comment: you can use single quotes and it different with the `smart quotes`.